# Many DataObjects with has_many relationship to one generic DataObject

Tags: silverstripe

I want to create a class that extends DataObject and simply has a Title, Desc, and Image.

```
class ImageBlock extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'Title' => 'Varchar(50)',
        'Description' => 'Varchar(255)'
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'Image' => 'Image'
    ];
}
```

This is generic Tile to display on the Frontend and could be shown on multiple pages and within multiple DataObjects. A given page or DO can have many of these. To clarify, this is not just for pages. I have a Region DO that has_many of these ImageBlocks:

```
class TourRegion extends \DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'RegionName' => 'Varchar(50)',
        'RegionSlug' => 'Varchar(50)',
        'RegionIntro' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'RegionDescription' => 'Text',
    ];

    private static $has_many = [
        'RegionHeroImages' => 'TourHeroImage',
        'MainAttractions' => 'ImageBlock'
    ];

    ....
```

My question is, a has_many to a DataObject requires a has_one relationship on that DataObject. Since the has_one relationship could be more than one possible class, how do I create this reference?

I have tried adding a has_one to the lowest common class that these objects share (DataObject) as follows:

```
class ImageBlock extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'Title' => 'Varchar(50)',
        'Description' => 'Varchar(255)'
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'Image' => 'Image',
        'ParentObject' => 'DataObject'
    ];
}
```

But I get this error:

> [User Error] Uncaught Exception: No has_one found on class
>   'ImageBlock', the has_many relation from 'TourRegion' to
>   'ImageBlock' requires a has_one on 'ImageBlock'

I get the same error when I try to omit this has_one on ImageBlock altogether. Which begs the question; Why is it I can add has_many relationships to DataObjects like Image or File without the Image or File class having a has_one reference to my Object?

It seems that it's not possible to have generic and reusable has_many related objects in Silverstripe. And that every class that needs to have this ImageBlock must duplicate the class for the sole purpose of adding the has_one reference.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the last part of your question, it's important to remember that `has_many` is schematically meaningless. It imposes no structural changes to your database. All it does is add a magic method to the parent DataObject that looks for a `has_one` somewhere else. Defining a `has_many` is basically just for convenience, to save you the time of writing a getter.

If you're looking to define the relation in the parent, which to me makes sense, I would do that as a `many_many`, as that requires no reciprocity (It can be reciprocated by `belongs_many_many`, but that is just a convenience method, too).

For consistency and clarity, I would create an extension to inject the `many_many => ImageBlock` to the DO's that want it.

Comment: Here is a [diagram of the ORM relations in SilverStripe](http://silverstrip.es/blog/diagram-of-relationships-in-silverstripe).

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain or link to what you mena in your last sentence. I'm not really seeing much of an answer here. So far as I can tell is it's not possible to have generic reusable objects in Silverstripe. The only way I can see how to do this have a base object, and then use that to extend a specific object for each parent that wants to use it. And all that is in those classes is a has_one relationship.

Comment: If you want something reusable and generic, then `has_many` is probably not the best approach. One way to do it, however, would be by creating a generic `ImageBlockHolder` (say, an abstract class), but that's a more vertical approach tat imposes an inheritance chain. If you wanted to do that, here is an example (http://sspaste.com/paste/show/58b281b17ea91).

Alternatively, a more horizontal approach using `many_many`, as I described above illustrated here (http://sspaste.com/paste/show/58b2828816cab)